# Selecting certain part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a column of strings in the format: 'a-b-c' where a, b and c can have any number of digits (e.g. 1-22-333, 120009-5555-1), how would I create new two new columns: 'a' and 'b'?

For example, from 1-22-333, I want two outputs: 1 and 22; from 120009-5555-1, I want 120009 and 5555:

```
String          a      b
1-22-333        1      22
120009-5555-1   120009 5555
```

Comment: you can see this question, it's the same i think,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784878/sql-regular-expression-to-split-a-column-string-to-multiple-rows-based-on-deli

Comment: @DJAMELDAHMANE  That one is for Oracle.  This one is for MS Sql Server.  I don't doubt that something similar to this question can be found on SO. But it's not that one.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/23628)

**Query 1**:

```
declare @s varchar(25) = '120009-5555-1'
select @s, left(@s, charindex('-', @s) - 1) as a, substring(@s, charindex('-', @s) + 1, charindex('-', @s, charindex('-', @s) + 1) - charindex('-', @s) - 1) as b
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/23628/0)**:

```
|               |      a |    b |  
|---------------|--------|------|  
| 120009-5555-1 | 120009 | 5555 |
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this for an entire column of these strings (vs. just one hardcoded string)?

Comment: Sure, if your column is named MyColumn, do:  `select MyColumn, left(MyColumn, charindex('-', MyColumn) - 1) as a, substring(MyColumn, charindex('-', MyColumn) + 1, charindex('-', MyColumn, charindex('-', MyColumn) + 1) - charindex('-', MyColumn) - 1) as b from MyTable`

Answer (score 2):

There exists also a little trick to abuse [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) for this.

For example:

```
SELECT val, 
REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(REPLACE(val,'-','.')),1)) as part1,
REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(REPLACE(val,'-','.')),2)) as part2
FROM (VALUES 
  ('12-345-6789'),
  ('1234-5678-90')
) q(val)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think substring is what you are looking for?

Example:

```
SELECT name, SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) AS Initial,
SUBSTRING(name, 3, 2) AS ThirdAndFourthCharacters
FROM sys.databases  
WHERE database_id < 5;
```

Source: 
[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score -1):

you can try this method that uses REGEX to spli a string :

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(myColumn,'^[0-9]+-'), // First part 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(myColumn,'-[0-9]+-'), // Midlle part
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(myColumn,'-[0-9]+$')  // last part 
   from mytable;
```

you can use after that substring to get the '-' out of each part